# Query IDs that match two conditions for an event - BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I would like to query my dataset (table) to get a column with user_ids, date, event name and event param key. I also specify that I only want 'LeaveReview' events.

```
fruit <- query_exec(
"SELECT user_dim.user_id, event.date, event.name, event_param.key,
FROM `table_201804*`,
UNNEST(event_dim) as event,
UNNEST(event.params) as event_param
WHERE event.name = 'LeaveReview'
AND _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '01' AND '25'
LIMIT 40",
project = "my_table"
```

)

How would I have to modify my code to get information only on those users that did BOTH 'LeaveReview' and 'ClickFavorite' on a given day? I tried the following, but that doesn't work:

```
fruit <- query_exec(
"SELECT user_dim.user_id, event.date, event.name, event_param.key,
FROM `table_201804*`,
UNNEST(event_dim) as event,
UNNEST(event.params) as event_param
WHERE (event.name = 'LeaveReview' AND event.name = 'ClickFavorite')
AND _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '01' AND '25'
LIMIT 40",
project = "my_table"
```

)

If I do the following, I will get people who did event 'ClickFavorite', but not event 'LeaveReview' or the other way around:

```
fruit <- query_exec(
"SELECT user_dim.user_id, event.date, event.name, event_param.key,
FROM `table_201804*`,
UNNEST(event_dim) as event,
UNNEST(event.params) as event_param
WHERE (event.name = 'LeaveReview' OR event.name = 'ClickFavorite')
AND _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '01' AND '25'
LIMIT 40",
project = "my_table"
```

)

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm.  Does something like this work?

```
SELECT user_dim.user_id
FROM `table_201804*`,
     UNNEST(event_dim) as event,
     UNNEST(event.params) as event_param
WHERE event.name  IN ('LeaveReview', 'ClickFavorite')
GROUP BY user_dim.user_id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT event.name) = 2;
```

Comment: I would still like to have all of the other information, such as event name, date and key, but I cannot include them because it will give me a warning "Error: SELECT list expression references event.name which is neither grouped nor aggregated"